# Change Google Map's axis of rotation

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google Map API in an Android app and trying to rotate the map. I have already done it by changing the bearing value but the problem is that it rotates around the center of the screen.

```
CameraPosition bottomPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .bearing(bearing)
                    .build();

mainMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(bottomPos));
```

I want to change its axis of rotation and make it rotate around a point at bottom of screen

Is there any function to change the axis of rotation of the map?

Comment: Please see answer update.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, you can use workaround like that - move map rotation center point to bottom of screen by creating `MapView` (`MapFragment`) twice as wide and as high and using margins align it position to center bottom like on a figure below:

[image: Move rotation center]

In that case, with default:

```
CameraPosition bottomPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .bearing(bearing)
                    .build();

mainMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(bottomPos));
```

your `mainMap` will turn around center of bottom of screen.

**UPDATE:**

Also you can use  get current map center screen coordinates, then change `y` coordinate and get new screen center. Something like that:

```
...
CameraPosition bottomPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .bearing(bearing)
                    .build();

mainMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(bottomPos));

LatLng mapCenter = mainMap.getCameraPosition().target;
Projection projection = mainMap.getProjection();
Point centerPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(mapCenter);

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

centerPoint.y = centerPoint.y - displayHeight / 2;  // move center down 

LatLng newCenterPoint = projection.fromScreenLocation(centerPoint);

mainMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newCenterPoint, zoom));
...
```